# JS VPAID - Is there a "standard" way that VPAID ads are rendered in the DOM by JS Video Players?

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, vast, google-ima

I've seen two ways in which VPAID Ads (not VPAID used for tracking) are rendered into the DOM by the Video Player.

1) The layering of elements in the DOM in the first example is something like the following (simplified for brevity):

```
<div id="videoPlayer">
<video class="playerVideoElement" src="pathToAdVideoAsset"></video>
<div id="adContainer">
<iframe id="adCreativeHTMLContent" class="overlaysVideoContent">
<html id="adCreativeDocument">
<div>//.. creative interactive content</div>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, the  element of the videoPlayer plays the VPAID ad video content while the  renders the interactive html ad creative content as an overlay of the ad video content. This is what appears to be happening with the JWPlayer:
https://developer.jwplayer.com/tools/ad-tester/

2) In the second example, there is a difference in that the  element of the videoPlayer never actually plays the ad video. This is because a completely separate DOM element is used to contain the entirety of the VPAID ad content:

```
<div id="videoPlayer">
<video class="playerVideoElement" src="pathToContentVideo"></video>
</div>
<div id="adContainer">
<video class="adSpecificVideoElement" src="pathToAdVideoAsset"></video>
<iframe id="adCreativeHTMLContent" class="overlaysVideoContent">
<html id="adCreativeDocument">
<div>//.. creative interactive content</div>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

In the second example, the content video remains in the videoPlayer's  element. The content videoPlayer is overlaid by a DOM element specifically used to contain and render all of the ad content. The ad video asset is loaded into a  element of the ad container and this is overlaid by the interactive html ad creative content. This can be observed by viewing the Google IMA execution: 
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector

Are these considered 'standard' video player methods of executing VPAID ads?

I'm curious because I've seen instances of VPAID where the ad video is rendered w/in a  element inside the creative html content and I wanted to know if this type of execution is common and/or also considered 'standard'.

3) example:

```
<div id="videoPlayer">
<video class="playerVideoElement" src="none_or_pathToContentVideo"></video>
<div id="adContainer">
<iframe id="adCreativeHTMLContent" class="overlaysVideoContent">
<html id="adCreativeDocument">
<video class="adVideoElement" src="pathToadVideo"></video>
<div>//.. creative interactive content</div>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of these are valid ways to display a preroll ad.
Typically, the more comprehensive VPAID ad managers such as the Google IMA will create a new video element that is separate from the content video. This allows them further control over the environment and tracking.